# Authorization on the site using OkHttp

Tags: android, authentication, authorization, okhttp

I’m trying to go to my university’s website and parse the necessary information (such as a schedule and so on). I checked the work on reqres.in and everything works, but on my site there is no answer (onFailure is called). I wrote all the same in Python, everything worked and the site started up. Maybe I’m missing something, I ask for help.

*Python code that works*

```
import requests
import re

s = requests.Session()
s.get("https://lk.sut.ru/cabinet/")

def login_bonch(login, password):
    data = {'users': login,
            'parole': password}

    r = s.post("https://lk.sut.ru/cabinet/lib/autentificationok.php", data = data)
    return r.text // Function returns 1
```

*Code in Android Studio that does not work*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("users", "username@gmail.com")
                .add("parole", "password123")
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://lk.sut.ru/cabinet/lib/autentificationok.php")
                .post(formBody)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                Log.d("SendLog", "Error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                Log.d("SendLog", " " + response.body().string());
            }
        });
    }
```

*I hope now attached the right (stack trace)*

```
2020-06-11 03:47:46.560 2287-2315/com.foxartstd.lkbonchapp W/System.err: java.net.ProtocolException: Too many follow-up requests: 21
2020-06-11 03:47:46.560 2287-2315/com.foxartstd.lkbonchapp W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:127)
2020-06-11 03:47:46.560 2287-2315/com.foxartstd.lkbonchapp W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
2020-06-11 03:47:46.560 2287-2315/com.foxartstd.lkbonchapp W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:197)
2020-06-11 03:47:46.560 2287-2315/com.foxartstd.lkbonchapp W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:502)
2020-06-11 03:47:46.560 2287-2315/com.foxartstd.lkbonchapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
2020-06-11 03:47:46.561 2287-2315/com.foxartstd.lkbonchapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
2020-06-11 03:47:46.561 2287-2315/com.foxartstd.lkbonchapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I can’t understand how to transfer the code from Python to the android application. I understand that maybe I'm missing the start of a web session, but I don’t know how to implement this in Java.

*The answer began to come, but I can’t show it. Added these lines*

```
ClearableCookieJar cookieJar =
                new PersistentCookieJar(new SetCookieCache(), new SharedPrefsCookiePersistor(getApplicationContext()));

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cookieJar(cookieJar)
                .followRedirects(FALSE)
                .followSslRedirects(FALSE)
                .build();
```

*I'm trying to get the answer like this, and I get only **Ok***

```
 client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                Log.d("SendLog", "Error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                String MyResult = response.body().string();
                Log.d("SendLog", "Ok " + MyResult);
            }
```

Comment: maybe you have to add an user agent to your request, just an estimation

Comment: Can you please show us the stack trace

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that's not quite the right stack trace - that's a harmless message from the runtime.   Specifically, we'd need the error printed by your `e.printStackTrace();` - I think, but am not certain, that the log tag would be `System.err`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Adding these lines solved my problem*

```
ClearableCookieJar cookieJar =
                new PersistentCookieJar(new SetCookieCache(), new SharedPrefsCookiePersistor(getApplicationContext()));

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cookieJar(cookieJar)
                .followRedirects(FALSE)
                .followSslRedirects(FALSE)
                .build();
```

*It was these deadlines that helped not to go wrong*

```
.followRedirects(FALSE)
.followSslRedirects(FALSE)
```

About the answer, these are already problems of the site. It returns 1 in case of success and all, otherwise nothing. Authorization is still not coming out, but the main issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `RequestBody.create` instead of `FormBody`

```
RequestBody formBody = RequestBody.create("application/json; charset=utf-8", "{\"users\":\"username@gmail.com\",\"parole\":\"password123\"}")
Request request = new Request.Builder()
          .url("https://lk.sut.ru/cabinet/lib/autentificationok.php")
          .post(formBody)
          .build();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, response does not come

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you will need a CookieJar to keep the session setup by the first call

Look at https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-cookie-jar/

https://github.com/franmontiel/PersistentCookieJar

```
ClearableCookieJar cookieJar =
                new PersistentCookieJar(new SetCookieCache(), new SharedPrefsCookiePersistor(context));
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cookieJar(cookieJar)
                .build();
```

But your code sample doesn't seem complete.

Comment: This did not solve my problem completely, but adding a couple of lines to `OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder ()` the answer began to come, but it was empty. There must be a number, I don’t know how to show it. Updated code.